# IntelliJ Add Framework Support missing Maven Option

Tags: java, scala, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to add a POM.XML file as per this documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/convert-a-regular-project-into-a-maven-project.html

It says I need to choose 'Maven' from 'Add Framework Support'. But I do not have that option. Why is this so, and how can I enable this option?

Also, I did see this previously in another project I opened in the same IntelliJ IDE on my computer. Does this mean it shows up based on my project contents?

I already have tried installing following maven plugins:

- Maven
- Maven Helper
- MavenPlugin
- Maven 2 Integration
- Maven Archetypes

Thank you!

Comment: if your workspace have pom.xml file and your workspace follows the maven directory structure like src/main/java, 1. exit or close your IntelliJ 2. Remove .idea folder and .iml file from your workspace. 3. open IntelliJ again and reimport the workspace again as maven project. It should import it corr

Comment: Is your project a Java/Kotlin? Please show screenshot with the steps you do.

Comment: Its a scala project. I will try to get screenshots. I don't have a pom.xml and the docs linked above are instructions to create POM file